# Qt: Subclassed spinbox does not count

Tags: c++, qt

I try to subclass a Qt spinbox so i can get the mouse event. The code compiles, the events are working, but the spinbox doesn't count up or down. I have set the min value to -9999 and max value to 9999, default value is 100. But if i click the up or down button, nothing happens.

NewSpinBox.h:

```
   #ifndef NEWSPINBOX_H
   #define NEWSPINBOX_H

   #include <QObject>
   #include <QWidget>
   #include <QEvent>
   #include <QMouseEvent>
   #include <QSpinBox>

   class NewSpinBox : public QSpinBox
   {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        NewSpinBox(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~NewSpinBox();
    public slots:
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
        void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
   };

   #endif // NEWSPINBOX_H
```

NewSpinBox.cpp:

```
#include "newspinbox.h"

NewSpinBox::NewSpinBox(QWidget *parent) : QSpinBox(parent)
{

}

NewSpinBox::~NewSpinBox()
{

}


void NewSpinBox::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(mouseEvent->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        int i = 0;
        i++;
    }
}

void NewSpinBox::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(mouseEvent->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        int i = 0;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Do I have to reimplement the count functions?

Comment: Added the .h file. Sorry for missing that.

Comment: This should fit into a single file, please study the posting guidelines, especially concerning the minimal example. That said, you override mousehandlers that might be important, but the baseclass won't receive those events any more because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call the base class handler to get the default behavior:

```
void NewSpinBox::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    QSpinBox::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
    // ... your code
}

void NewSpinBox::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    QSpinBox::mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
    // ... your code
}
```